# What is the workaround for Medtronic Carelink Ubuntu compatibility?

Tags: 12.10, usb

I am taking a wild shot here: I am a type 1 diabetic who is going on the Insulin pump.  Unfortunately, the Medtronic Carelink USB device that uploads data from the pump online only has windows drivers.  Has anybody managed to get this working under Ubuntu using Wine or by any other method?

`lsusb` yields:

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0a21:8001 Medtronic Physio Control Corp. MMT-7305WW [Medtronic Minimed CareLink]
```

I really don't want to buy a Windows machine just for this, but it's probably one in a million that somebody else has managed to make this work under Linux.

Comment: - I have not been able to find any software. I would suggest posting a question for support on http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/  and ubuntuforums.org Get more attention to it and someone with coding skill might be able to pull it off  
- `Windows machine` that is not required; all you need is a license to legally use Windows. And if students in Europe can get one for less than 25 euro you should be able too ;)

Comment: Good luck and please post here if you figure it out. I could not even get this dongle to work in Chrome *on Windows*, so I didn't even bother trying on Linux. Our best prospect may be to prevail upon Medtronic to add official support, and that's probably not very likely. :(

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to run any windows driver via wine. There is a slim chance that the device is actually compatible with something else. For example I have many factory equipment which can be connected to as if it is a modem, via minicom. 
However, finding this out is tricky and can be answered only by the guy who knows how this medical things are built. 
You can install Windows as an application via VirtualBox. However, if you are licencse-aware, microsoft prohibits it.

Comment: Yep, Virtualbox is very likely to work though this is a tedious workaround. The license issue is for a court to decide, but from a technical perspective this looks like it solves the question.

Comment: "However, if you are licencse-aware, microsoft prohibits it." Even when the Windows system on the VM has its own, separate license? I'm not a lawyer and I don't have my Windows license agreements in front of me at this moment. But based on widespread use of virtualized Windows systems in the enterprise and how Microsoft is itself a vendor of virtualization software intended for Windows guests, as well as my own memory of what Windows license agreements that I have signed have said (I have actually read them, all the way through), it seems unlikely that Microsoft even claims to prohibit this.

Comment: Licenses for cheaper versions of Window$, like Home, explicitely prohibit use in virtual machines. I don't know what about Win8.

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/how-the-new-windows-8-license-terms-affect-you-7000003028/ covered this in some detail. Basically, under all the Windows 8 licenses, you get to install and run *1* copy of Windows. You don't get to share that license between a bare metal install and a VM install. Pro and Enterprise licenses may give you additional rights, but they are not necessary to use the single copy - they may be necessary to dual boot, or to run multiple VMs off the same license though.

Answer (score 2):

It is  possible to log in to the website if you spoof your headers.

1. To do this you install a plugin like **Modify Headers 0.7.1.1**
2. Click Preferences
3. Select Headers -> Modify
   Headername: `user-agent`
   Headervalue: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)`
4. Start the plugin

Now you can log in to the site from Ubuntu to generate reports and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

With the `lsusb` output above, you can use linux software, written in python or node, to talk fetch logs from your pump.

You didn't specify exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to fetch information from the pump and save it in, eg a json file, you can use the `mm-latest.py` script to do that in Ubuntu.

To create a serial device, `insert.sh` from the decoding-carelink package Which runs:

```
#Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0a21:8001 Medtronic Physio Control Corp. 
sudo modprobe --first-time usbserial vendor=0x0a21 product=0x8001
```

Now any linux tool of your choice can talk to the pump, so long as it knows how to use the pump's protocol.
There is some software available to do this:

#### openaps

There's a tool called [openaps](https://github.com/openaps/openaps).
This provides a [number of commands](https://github.com/bewest/openaps-example), replete with tab-completion.

Installing:

```
# install openaps from pypi
sudo easy_install -ZU openaps
```

Now we can create a new instance of openaps, and begin **using** the devices we'll configure:

```
openaps init my.openaps # creates new subdirectory/git repo called my.openaps
openaps device add pump medtronic AABBCC # where AABBCC is your serial number
openaps use pump read_clock # to read current clock
openaps use pump iter_pump 100 # for last 100 pump records
openaps use pump -h # for menu of all commands
```

The system will also aide in storing the results to files tracked by the git repo.

#### decoding-carelink

Under the hood openaps is using [decoding-carelink](https://github.com/bewest/decoding-carelink) to talk to the pump.
This is like a `curl` and `libcurl` for medtronic pumps, it exposes a python library for getting data from the pumps, as well as some useful commandline tools to do common tasks, such as retrieving logs from specified time period.  There are also some udev rules provided to help create the serial device automatically..

comlink2-uart

- in node js, [comlink2-uart](https://github.com/bewest/comlink2-uart) provides javascript bindings for similar purposes

Once you get the data, you can use your favorite visualization program to share or visualize the data.

So the alternatives to windows and carelink software are the these two projects, which liberates your data on your own terms.

Comment: Please let me know if I can improve this answer if it's not up to norms.

Comment: That looks fine, but I'm no expert on the topic.

Comment: Hi there, moderator here. I see now that you did indeed improve your old answer and make it up to our standards. However, we can't track actions that happen on deleted posts, so next time (after editing it) flag it for a moderator and let us know, then we can undelete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My girlfriend she has the carelink usb too. It really is an annoying thing. The Internet Explorer is mandatory and therefore Windows, just to run a Java (sic!) application ...

And if it weren't such an important thing, this little stick and this tiny pump. One could try to find out the settings of the hardware through which the datas are loaded into the application.

Yet no experiments with life savers (even if I assume, that it should be real simple the transmitting protocol). Unfortunately Medtronic doesn't care.

So unfortunately, it works until now within a Virtual Machine e.g. VirtualBox which comes with this license issue.