# Uninstall ubuntu reinstall Windows

Tags: 12.04

My son installed Ubuntu on my laptop for me to use I like it except my insulin pump only uses Windows. I know nothing about the structuring of the HD. I have the windows 2000 full installation disk and the Windows vista upgrade disk. I do not have a recovery disk cause my son didn't make one before uninstalling windows and putting Ubuntu on.

I believe it was due to windows crashing that he went to Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You can have both Ubuntu and Windows if you want see here:http://askubuntu.com/a/163249/107450.  But if you want just Windows make sure the BIOS is set to boot from CD and boot the Windows 2000 disk.  It should install replacing Ubuntu.  Once done you can use the Vista upgrade disk to upgrade to Vista.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/225255/what-is-the-workaround-for-medtronic-carelink-ubuntu-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If it is just that specific program that you are switching back to windows for, have you tried installing 'wine' in Ubuntu and running it on there? Wine tries to emulate Windows so you can run (some) Windows programs, so it might be worth a try if you wanted.

As far as removing Ubuntu and installing Windows, the general procedure is to insert the Windows disc at startup and then you should get on screen instructions on installing Windows. As far as where Windows would install (by the sounds of it you are looking to install over Ubuntu) I do not know the options available during Windows setup, I believe this is a question better answered on a Windows forum.

Comment: Wine is not effective for most Windows *hardware*; it does not facilitate running device drivers. This appears to be the OP's situation.